# 英語が残っている: 表示できるアカウントがない時のネットワークプロフィールバナー画像

Tags: バグ, 延期, 翻訳, 英語

[community user flair http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/-1.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/-1.png)

[コミュニティユーザー](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)の[バナーページ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community/flair)で確認可能です (モデレーターのみ)。

Comment: バナーは別のサービスのため、まだ多言語化はされていません。これを実行するため大幅な変更が必要し、まだ計画はしていません。ニーズがあれば検討ができますが、これは「edge-case」であるため、あまり優先度が高くないと思っています。

Answer (score 1):

> You do not have any linked accounts with 200+ rep

200点以上信用度のあるアカウントがありません